# Regex: how to find the maximum integer value of a pattern?

Tags: c++, regex, boost, format

Imagine I have the following string:

```
"I'll have some %1%, some %42% and maybe some %5% as well."
```

Basically, I am interested in knowing the maximum integer value that follow the pattern %(integer)%.

I am not even sure it's possible to do with a regex. What regex could I use so that in the above example the answer would be 42?

P.S. One easy solution is evidently to simply look for any %(integer)% patterns, and use the script (c++ code) to iterate through all the matches and find the highest value. My question is: is it possible to do it straight away within the regex?

**Background**: understanding what follows is probably not necessary to answer the question, but I thought some of you might want to know.

Basically I am using C++ and boost::format. Formats are patterned with placeholders like this: %1%, %2%, etc. Boost::format throws an exception if the number of supplied variables do not correspond to the maximum integer value in the format itself. The formats I am going to use are supplied by (trusted) users (web site administrators). Still, to do things properly, I need to validate the patten. Thus, I need to find the maximum integer in the pattern to make sure no exception will be thrown at run time.

If you are using boost::format with user-supplied formats, how did you deal with this issue?

BTW, there is no boost-format tag! (although there are other boost-foo tags).

**Solution**

[Billy ONeal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170440/regex-how-to-find-the-maximum-integer-value-of-a-pattern/4170472#4170472) provided the right answer and Beh Tou Cheh (in the comments to the selected answer) was kind enough to [paste](http://pastie.org/1294443) the actual code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <deque>
#include "strtk.hpp"

int main() 
{
   std::string s = "I'll have some %1%, some %42% and maybe some %5% as well.";
   std::deque<int> int_list;
   strtk::split_regex("%([\\d]+)%",
                       s,
                       strtk::range_to_type_back_inserter(int_list),
                       strtk::match_mode::match_1);

   if (!int_list.empty())
   {
        std::cout << "max: " << strtk::max_of_cont(int_list) << std::endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know the boost::regex library well enough to answer (just learning it), but I'd advise against anything but the simple solution you suggest yourself. Though Perl hackers may tell you otherwise, this is not what regexps are intended to do. They're nice for matching strings but a poor choice for arithmetic.

Comment: Really, don't make things more complicated by trying to cram it all into the regex. Just iterate.

Comment: I would just try to pass the parameters to the format string and convert it into a string, all within a try-catch statement that catches a bad format exception. Really, there's no simple way for you to validate the format string other than to try it. For example, the format string allows printf-syntax too. Otherwise, if you really want to do it, just iterate with a simple regex: "%\d+%".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Find all values like this: `%([\d]+)%`, parse the back reference as an integer (using something like `lexical_cast`), and choose the highest value. (You can use something like `std::max_element` for this)

Comment: I.e., don't iterate over the solutions but let the library do it for you :)

Comment: @Billy: you'd need to trim leading and trailing "%" as the regex you've provided will return those, and lexical_cast will barf a bad_lexical_cast exception if it seems them.

Comment: @Beh Tou Cheh: Did you notice the parenthesis in the regular expression? Those are important. Don't use the whole match, use the backreference.

Comment: @Billy: I just tried it with boost regex (1.44) and it returns the integer with "%" symbol. eg: boost::sregex_iterator itr(s.begin(),s.end(),"%([\\d]+)%");   should it be done some other way?  I think the default mode for boost regex is posix regex

Comment: @Beh: Use `regex_match::operator[]` ;) (match[1] should contain the first backreference, which in this case is just the number)

Comment: @Billy: I see, so it seems like the default is match[0] (everything) when derefrencing a boost::sregex_iterator.

Comment: @Billy: Not 100% sure, but I thought it was called a captured group, and a backreference is how you match the same group multiple times in the same regex.

Comment: @Ben: I believe you are correct. In my mind backreference == captured group, because they do the same thing in the source text.

Comment: Using Billy's suggestions and StrTk, I've got the following solution: http://pastie.org/1294443

Answer (score 0):

Even if someone did devise a regex capable of doing that, it would not perform as well as simply iterating the matches.